# How can I create or query several SMB shares via powershell or in C#

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, smb

I am trying to create thousands of file shares, if they don't exist already.

I've to do this, because I am working on a legacy system.

Doing this synchronously, in a single thread is taking an insanely long time. I am working on making it multi-threaded, but it'd be great if I could:

- create
- check for the presence of

several SMB shares with 1 C# API/powershell command. I've been trying to google the answer for quite some time now and haven't found any useful results. :(

Comment: The command `Get-SMBShare` will get you a list of SMB shares on a particular machine. The command `New-SMBShare` will allow you to create.

Comment: @jrider Based on "legacy system", those commands aren't available.  Which means they have to rely on `NET.exe SHARE`

Comment: `Invoke-CimMethod` can be used to create shares and `Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Share` can be used to check for their presence. This works on "legacy" Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Using CIM cmdlets requires PS version 3.0 or greater, so for getting share `win32_share` is the best candidate and for creating use `net share`. You caould create the script to run locally and wrap it up in `Invoke-Command` , `-ComputerName` accepts array of computer and it will handle batching and threading.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Servers -ScriptBlock { #your command }
```

Or

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Servers -FilePath <your script path>
```

See `-ThrottleLimit` parameter as well for batching.

`Get-Help Invoke-Command -Full`

Answer (score 0):

There is still information to be documented about the servers and SHARENAMEs you are creating. Is it the same SHARENAME on all COMPUTERNAMEs? Is it one COMPUTERNAME with many SHARENAMEs? This code might give you some ideas. This runs on Windows 7 with the current PowerShell 5.1.

```
#   Find CIM classes about shares.
#
#   Get-CimClass | Where-Object { $_.CimClassName -match '.*share.*' }
#
#   Find out which shares are already available.
#
#   Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Share
#
#   Find class methods
#
#   Get-CimClass | Where-Object { $_.CimClassName -match '.*share.*' } | ForEach-Object { $_.CimClassMethods }
#
#   Find the arguments of a method.
#
#   (Get-CimClass -ClassName Win32_Share).CimClassMethods['Create'].Parameters

$Arguments = @{
    Path = 'C:\Users\Public'
    Name = 'TESTSHARE_TTTTTTTTTT';
    Type = [uint32]0;
}

Invoke-CimMethod -ClassName Win32_Share -MethodName Create -Arguments $Arguments
```